# How to load UnSlider with JQuery Ajax load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using UnSlider for my website, and I'm using Jquery Ajax Load function 
Whitout using Jquery load(), Unslider works, but with Jquery load(), Unslider isn't loaded.
Here's my code: 
 JS

```
function ChangeUrl(page, url) {
        if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
            var obj = { Page: page, Url: url };
            history.pushState(obj, obj.Page, obj.Url);
        } else {
            alert("Browser does not support HTML5.");
        }
}
function LoadMe() {
    $("#content").fadeOut();
    $("#content").load("me #ajax_content");
    ChangeUrl('me', 'me');
    $(".banner").unslider({
      speed: 500,
      delay: 3000,  
      complete: function() {},
      keys: false,
      dots: true,
      fluid: true
    });
    $("#content").fadeIn();
}
```

HTML :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="unslider.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
1234
</div>
<p onclick="LoadMe()">Load !</p>
```

Comment: Why do you need to use jQuery load()?

Comment: @navasd beacause I want to use it to make my site beautiful and dynamic.

Comment: You need your unslider code to wait until after .load() is complete. Use the 'complete' callback function of .load() to run your code.

Comment: @clayton-leis Thanks !